# How can I show only direct taxonomy children?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am adding some custom code for a taxonomy.php WordPress-page. I do NOT know how to write php. This has taken me 3 days already, and i'm trying to customize it.

It is exactly how I want it now, except I only want to display direct children of the current taxonomy.

Can someone help me change this to show only direct children, not all children?

```
<?php
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ); 
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
$url = get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name );
$name = $term->name;
$image = get_field('taxonomy_image', $term );
$description = get_term_field( 'description', $term );
echo '<div class="sub-category">';
echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '<div class="sub-category-image"><img src="' . esc_url($image['url']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($image['alt']) . '" /></div><div class="sub-category-description">' . $description . '</div></a>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

**Background info (don't know if this is relevant):**
It is a custom taxonomy "area" made with the plugin "CPT UI". The custom taxonomies also include custom fields from "Advanced Custom Fields". I want to show the taxonomies and not the posts on all taxonomies with children.

**EDIT**
I... "customized" the code according to the link provided for me in the comments, but as I said, PHP is not my language.

My code now looks like this:

```
    <?php
    $term_children = get_terms( 'produktkategori', array( 'parent' => get_queried_object_id(), ) );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
            $image = get_field( 'taxonomy_image', $term );
            $description = get_term_field( 'description', $term );
            echo '
            <div class="sub-category">
            <a href="' . get_term_link( $child ) . '">
            <div class="sub-category-image">
            <img src="' . esc_url($image['url']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($image['alt']) . '" /></div>
            <div class="sub-category-description">
            <h3>' . $child->name . '</h3>
            ' . $description . '
            </div>
            </a>
            </div>
            ';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Which in turn actually gave me only direct taxonomy children (which I wanted) but the image and description showing with the child taxonomies are THEIR child's taxonomy image and description. Sooo...

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124347/get-term-children-for-immediate-children-only-not-grandchildren

Comment: As I do not know how to write php and therefore don't know how to customize it, can you be helpful as to what it is I need to change?